# How to get VictoryAxis tickValues evenly distributed on the axis in victory-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, victory-charts

I'm trying to make a temperature gauge that looks like a mercury thermometer. To do this I'm using Formidable Lab's victory native library.

Where I'm running into trouble is in getting the `VictoryAxis` component to spread its `VictoryLabel` components evenly along the y-axis.

My loop in `componentDidMount` is generating an array of numbers, in increments of 0.2, between the range of `this.state.cLower` and `this.state.cUpper` that are supposed to be set as the tick labels on the y-axis.

```
export default class Thermometer extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        temp: [0],
        cUpper: 29,
        cLower: 24,
        tickValues: []
      }
      DB.ref('tempLog').limitToLast(1).on('value', snap => {
        this.setState({ temp: [{ x: 0, y: [snap.val()[Object.keys(snap.val())[0]].temp] }], y0: this.state.cLower })
      })
    }
    componentDidMount () {
      let temps = new Set()
      for (let i = parseFloat(this.state.cLower); i <= parseFloat(this.state.cUpper); i += 0.2) {
        temps.add(Math.round(i * 10) / 10)
      }
      this.setState({ tickValues: Array.from(temps) })
    }

    render () {
      return (
        <VictoryChart
          height={300}
          width={65}>
          <VictoryAxis
            style={{ ticks: { size: 12 } }}
            orientation={'left'}
            tickValues={this.state.tickValues}
            dependentAxis />
          <VictoryBar
            style={{ data: { fill: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' } }}
            data={this.state.temp} />
        </VictoryChart>
      )
    }
  }
```

I've verified that the values rendered are correct but as you can see here all the labels get rendered nearly on top of each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this.state.cLower` and `this.state.cUpper` set the bounds for the lower and upper data, respectively, that is rendered I had to set `VictoryBar`'s `y0` prop to the value of `this.state.cLower`

```
<VictoryBar
 y0={() => this.state.cLower}
 style={{ data: { fill: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' } }}
 data={this.state.temp} />
```

`VictoryAxis` then picks up on this, presumably through `VictoryChart`, and the `VictoryAxis`' `VictoryLabel`s get distributed, and the rendered `VictoryBar` data aligned as expected

[image]